# ElasticSearch Date Format with fractional-second support

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch, datetime-format

I am trying to insert a Date Time mapping into ElasticSearch that supports fractional-second format symbols.

An example of the Timestamp value in my Json Documents is:

`2019-09-03T19:55:01.8127303Z`

So, to map these values into the index, I used this Date Format:

```
custom_date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ";
"properties" : {
"Timestamp": {  
                    "type":   "date",
                    "format": custom_date_format
            },
#(...etc...)
}
```

When I insert documents with this mapping, there is an error:

```
{"type":"illegal_argument_exception",
"reason":"failed to parse date field [2019-09-03T18:51:45.7506712Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ]",
"caused_by":{"type":"date_time_parse_exception",
"reason":"Text \'2019-09-03T18:51:45.7506712Z\' could not be parsed at index 27"}}}
```

I don't see an error with the date format, except that there are no examples of datetimes of this type on ElasticSearch docs.

Two questions:

1. Can this format be used to parse the datetimes of this type?
2. Is it possible to skip over the last 7 digits of the fractional second entirely when parsing them? They are not necessary, but in the raw documents I obtain, its the way they are provided.

Answer (score 1):

Date Formatting in Elastic Search is not possible to begin with. The only way to get them working is to use the Java methods, not Python.

I would either convert these to integer-based unix time values, or do a raw full-text queries when doing range-queries on these documents.